# Python: I'm getting an error when using self.name

Tags: python, oop, self

I made 2 programs, one that works here:

```
class dog:
    amount_of_dogs = 0

    def __init__(self, name, playfulness):

        self.name = name
        self.playfulness = playfulness
        dog.amount_of_dogs += 1

dog1 = dog("Ruffer", 1000)

dog2 = dog("Skipper", 400)

dog3 = dog("El Diablo", 30000000)
print "The dog names are:", dog1.name, ",", dog2.name, ",", dog3.name, "."
print dog1.name, "'s happiness is ", dog1.playfulness, "!"
print dog2.name, "'s happiness is ", dog2.playfulness, "!"
print dog3.name, "'s happiness is ", dog3.playfulness, "!"
```

It works, no prob! But then, I made a second, longer program (This is just a snippet)

```
class enemy:
    global enemy_attack
    global enemy_health
    global enemy_name

    amount_of_enemies = 0

    def __init__(self, name, enemy_attack, enemy_health):
        self.name = enemy_name
        self.enemy_attack = enemy_attack
        self.enemy_health = enemy_health
        enemy.amount_of_enemies += 1

"""ENEMY STATS"""   
witch = enemy("witch", 40, 200)

print witch.enemy_name, witch.enemy_attack, witch.enemy_health
```

It throws the error:

```
enemy_name is not defined!
```

Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are trying to print

```
print witch.enemy_name
```

But the attribute is

```
self.name = enemy_name
```

So you should be calling

```
print witch.name
```

Comment: But what if I want to access the global variable associated with the class, say I modify the global variable using class instance, this in turn creates an instance of the global variable as local variable belonging to class. Having done this, If I print witch.enemy_name, what is the expected output? the global value or the instantiated local value?

Comment: I used CoryKramer's idea, but it still threw an error. He got 1/2 of the story right. I then found that if I replaced the self, name, enemy_attack... with self, enemy_name, enemy_attack... it works! Thx CoryKramer, though, for helping with 1/2 of it. =D

Comment: "But what if I want to access the global variable associated with the class" : there's NO such thing as a "global variable associated with the class". There are global variables (module global that is) and local variables - "local" to the current scope, which can be a function statement body or a class statement body. Note that unless explicitly deleted, class statement body's variables become class attributes. Also note that class statement body's variable are NOT available to the local scope of functions defined within the class statement.

Comment: @CoryKramer sorry but wrong answer (even if you did spot the next bug ;))

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the error is not the `print witch.enemy_name` line (which would have raised an AttributeError, not a NameError), but the `self.name = enemy_name` (first line in `enemy.__init__`) - the parameter is named (no pun) `name`, not `enemy_name`. Note that the global statement is only useful within a function body, and that it does not *define* a variable, it only specifies that in the current function the name is to be considered as global.